# Retrying multipart upload request stalls in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, promise

I am using a library that retries promises if they fail. I have a function that uploads an image to our server, which can sometimes fail due to a poor internet connection.

The promise successfully re-fires when the request returns an error, but the subsequent request is then stalled for 1-2 minutes. I am only seeing this problem in Chrome and not Safari (macOS 10.12).

Chrome's [developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/issues) states that a request may be stalled if there are 6 open TCP connections to the endpoint, but there are no open requests when the retry is attempted.

To be sure, the previous attempt is complete - there is no open connection, because the server returned with an error response code. Looking at headers, I see the server is responding with `Connection: keep-alive`, but I'm not sure if that should be affecting the result I'm seeing.

Is there any way to debug what could be causing the request stalling? Is there a way to see what connections Chrome currently has open?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is still of interest to the author, but in case someone else spends half a day trying to figure out the cause of successive Ajax requests that work properly in any other browser but get stalled and finally cancelled in Chrome, deactivate the Ad Blocker extension(or similar one), if you have it installed.

**UPDATE TO MY PREVIOUS ANSWER**

We thought we had resolved our issues after removing Ad Blocker, but turns out it was a problem connected to our network. The requests works perfectly in one of our offices and on external connections using VPN, meanwhile, in one office, the problem appears regardless of the existence of Ad Blocker...

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've definitely run into issues because of ad blockers, but I saw this behavior on machines that weren't running any kind of extensions or blockers at all.